# How can I install missing perl modules on an embedded system?

Tags: perl, embedded-linux

I'm running Linux on an embedded system, specifically Yocto Linux on a Cyclone V FPGA. I'm able to use Perl in its most basic form, but I'm unable to load any Perl modules. For example, when trying to use the `GetOpt::Long` module, I get the following error

```
root@socfpga_cyclone5:/mnt/sdcard# ./test.pl
Can't locate Getopt/Long.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
  /etc/perl
  /usr/lib/perl/site_perl/5.14.2/
  /usr/lib/perl/site_perl/5.14.2
  /usr/lib/perl/vendor_perl/5.14.2/
  /usr/lib/perl/vendor_perl/5.14.2
  /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/
  /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2
  /usr/local/lib/site_perl
  /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2
  .) at ./test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 3.
```

Does anybody know how I can go about installing these modules? Do the modules depend on hardware architecture at all? Is it reasonable to just copy and paste the `.pm` files somewhere from some source (and where would I be able to find and download these `.pm` files)?

Comment: What problems do you have with the normal method of installing modules?

Comment: What is the normal method of install modules?

Comment: Using its installer, via `cpan`, usually.

Comment: the usual system is not so good for embedded. Tends to be slow and eats lots of space, and pulls things you may not need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this thread: https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-July/015198.html

It sounds like perl modules have been packaged by whatever other thing needed first, but someone is working on making them available separately.

Some modules could be installed by just copying; others require a compiler or other build steps first.  You are best off using whatever tools the yocto project provides.

Answer (score 15):

I know your question is more than two years old, but it's a good question and I'm sad that nobody has answered it.

The perl ecosystem is very large, and the disk footprint of a full-featured perl installation is a problem on embedded systems. For that reason only a minimal system is installed when you add `perl` to your image. Other perl modules are available as bitbake packages.

Most of the time you can figure out what packages a recipe offers from the recipe, but the perl recipe is very complicated. The easiest way to find out what packages are built by the perl recipe is to build it (`bitbake perl`) and then look in the packages-split directory, which you will find in your bitbake work directory. For my system (cortex A8) that looks something like this:

```
$ ls -1 /poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/perl/5.20.0-r1/packages-split
perl
perl-dbg
perl-dev
perl-doc
perl-lib
perl-lib.shlibdeps
perl-misc
perl-misc.shlibdeps
perl-module-anydbm-file
perl-module-app-cpan
perl-module-app-prove
perl-module-app-prove-state
(...)
```

If the module you want is listed, just add it to `IMAGE_INSTALL` like this:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "\
    perl \
    perl-module-base \
    perl-module-bytes \
    perl-module-data-dumper \
    perl-module-digest-md5 \
    perl-module-file-spec \
    perl-module-file-spec-functions \
    perl-module-findbin \
    perl-module-getopt-long \
    (...)"
```

If you want a module that isn't already being build, you will need to make your own recipe for it using the `cpan` class. See the examples in `poky/meta/recipes-extended/perl` and `/poky/meta/recipes-lsb4/perl`.

Editorializing, I've not been very happy with using perl on embedded systems. The biggest issue is the deferral of dependency resolution until runtime. It's too easy to mess this up and end up with `Can't locate foobar.pm in @INC` errors.